# Reading a 2d array from file in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, 2d, scanf

I have a 2d array filled with characters like '#' and '$' which I have read into a file. I am now trying to load this 2d array and print it. The 2d array is defined below in main.

The 2d array is n × n (n is the height and width of the 2d array), where n is a user inputted value.

```
char **board = (char **)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    board[i] = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
```

I have this function that first writes the 2d array to a file. This works completely fine. The function is then supposed to read the 2d array and print it, but the program just stops. I assume I have the fscanf() code wrong.

```
void createTxtFile(char **board, int n)
{
    char filename[100];
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp1;
    printf("Enter Game Title: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
    printf("Could not create file");
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < n; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            fprintf(fp,"%c ", board[r][c]);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file");
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < n; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            fscanf(fp1, "%c ", board[r][c]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);

    for(int r = 0; r < n; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            printf("%c", board[r][c]);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Printing "Could not open file", then continuing on to use an invalid FILE variable is called "undefined behaviour"

Comment: `fscanf(fp1, "%c ", board[r][c]);` is wrong, enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `board[i] = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));` is wrong as well.

Comment: Voting to close as boring typo. To avoid troubleshooting bugs that the compiler has already found for you, study [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) Btw if you used actual 2D arrays with contiguously allocated memory, you could read/write this in one go with a single fread/fwrite, no loops needed.